# IE8 li:hover, hover is triggered on margin between li items?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, hover

The first menu item has a dropdown submenu that is supposed to display on li:hover. For some reason though, hovering on the margins between ANY of the li's is causing the submenu to display and I can't figure out why. It works in Chrome and IE in compatibility mode, but not IE8.

Here's the line of CSS that displays the submenu:

```
.menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    }
```

To me, that reads that whenever you hover an li, style any of it's children ul's with the following style. Why would this be getting triggered on margins between li's that don't have nested ul's?

Here's the entire CSS for the menu just in case:

```
.menu {
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 1.1em;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 5px 0 0 0;
font-family: OswaldLight;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu li {
list-style: none;
float: left; 
margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none; 
padding:5px;
color:@navbar-text;
background:@navbar;
text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li ul {
display: none; 
background-color: @navbar;

}

.menu li ul li {
margin: 0;
}

.menu li a:hover {
color: @navbar-text-highlight;
background-color: @navbar-highlight; 
}

.menu li:hover ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}

.menu li:hover li {
float: none; 
}

.menu li:hover li a {
background-color: @navbar;
color: @navbar-text;
}

.menu li li a:hover {
color: @navbar-text-highlight;
background-color: @navbar-highlight; 
}
```

Comment: Id try removing the margin from your <li> replacing with padding to the right of the anchor and triggering hover on anchor

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I'd prefer to avoid it because I don't want the parent menu item to be a link, only the nested items, but if that's the only solution then I will have to settle.

Comment: Dont think it would have to be a link

Comment: If I change the dropdown hover to only trigger on a:hover though, how would the drop down appear if the drop down parent had no anchor? Is it possible to enclose some text in an <a> tag that is not a link?

Comment: It actually behaves a lot better when using the margin on the anchor instead of the li, and I can infact just do <a>stuff</a> with no link being created, but li a:hover ul {} doesn't target the nested UL since it's not contained with the anchor... Hmph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering, the problem was the "display:table" in the .menu class. The .menu class was assigned to the parent UL and IE8 didn't know what to do with it. I removed that line, added a parent  around the parent  and gave that "display:table" instead and it seemed to solve the problem. The reason I'm using "display:table" is to clear my floats but allow me to easily center the contained floats using "margin: 0 auto", which seems to be the nicest solution I've found for centering a container of floats.

Answer (score 0):

It probably ha something to do with the width that ul with the sub menu, I will have to look into it further but most likely it's a width issue in IE

Update: well it seems you fixed it